# Writing a Simple SMTP Client in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, smtpclient

I'm looking for some guidance regarding the implementation of a painfully simple SMTP Client to familiarize myself with how such a thing works. I would just like to be able to securely connect to and interact with an imap server(such as "imap.google.com") and handle basic sending and receiving of emails. I'm attempting to write this using the libraries available to Windows 8 Metro Apps, which **excludes** System.Net.Mail(Which is what the previous implementation used).

I've looked at other implementations that claim to be simple and relatively speaking I'm sure they are, but to someone of my experience they leave me horribly lost. I've been searching google as well as looking for similar questions/answers here but have come up empty handed and remain confused.

Any resources in the form of explanations, tutorials, crystal clear implementations with explanations, really any nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: SMTP client... which uses IMAP? SMTP is quite simple to implement. You can Google for the spec and have a basic working client within an few hours. IMAP... is a whole other can of worms.

Comment: I was afraid of something like that :( My previous implementation was able to handle everything in a straightforward fashion, but most of the built in libraries that I used are not supported for Win8 Metro Apps, really makes this a pain in the butt. Is it easy to implement the spec in C#? I'll take a look at it now.